# Linq passing multiple list in where condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, where-clause

I am getting result from db by passing filters. Currently i have passed `code` list and i am getting correct data. Below is the code.

```
public DataTable getData(IList<string> Code, 
                         IList<string> category, 
                         IList<string> state, 
                         IList<string> Type, 
                         IList<string> general)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var result = _db.Sample.Where(x => Code.Contains(x.Code));

    if (result == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        dt = Utility.ToDataTable(result.ToList());
    }

    return dt;
}
```

I have to pass 4 more filters ,i.e, `category, state, type and general`. Also i have to check if none of them is null.

I am not sure how to check the values for null and then pass it to the query.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if all the 5 are null and then execute the `lambda` expression. And for adding conditions for 4 extra filters use `&&` operator and add it along with code filter.

```
public DataTable getData(IList<string> Code, IList<string> category, IList<string> state, IList<string> Type, IList<string> general)

        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

              if(code==null)
              code=''
              if(category==null)
              category=''
              if(state==null)
              state=''
              if(general==null)
              general=''               

              var result = _db.Sample.Where(x => (Code.Contains(x.Code) || Code=='') && (category.Contains(x.category)|| category=='') && (state.Contains(x.state)||state=='') && (general.Contains(x.general)||general==''))


            if (result == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                dt = Utility.ToDataTable(result.ToList());
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: this will not execute the query if code is null or any other parameter is null i want to check if any of the parameter has value then apply in where condition

Comment: @OwaisAhmed Updated my answer

Comment: @JibinBalachandran won't this throw null exception when any of them is null, since the null check is done after the contains check?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran The change you have done just adds more lines of code. Doesn't the answer I have given look precise than this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to check contains for all list or just for any one of them. I', giving the solution for both

```
 public DataTable getData(IList<string> Code, IList<string> category, IList<string> state, IList<string> Type, IList<string> general)

    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var result = null;
        //result = _db.Sample.Where(x => Code.Contains(x.Code) && category.Contains(x.category) && state.Contains(x.state) && general.Contains(x.general));
        //if you wish to check for any one
        result = _db.Sample.Where(x => (Code != null && Code.Contains(x.Code)) || (category != null && category.Contains(x.category)) || (state != null && state.Contains(x.state)) || (general != null && general.Contains(x.general)));


        if (result == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            dt = Utility.ToDataTable(result.ToList());
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: but if any of the parameter is null then it will not execute the query. I also want to if any one of them contains value

Comment: @OwaisAhmed I have edited my answer to suit your above query

Comment: @JibinBalachandran Haha.. Thanks for that :)